# Progress dialog keeps on displaying in android studio

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio, yii

I am newbie to android development. I am using `android studio` for my application. I have created a `DB` and then created a `web service` in Yii, tested it on `ARC` and use the `GET` method and it shows the result perfectly. After that i created an `app` in which i want to use the `web service` and use it's get method to display a result.

Below is my DB table structure

[image]

The scenario is when ever a user enters the `id` in the app and hit the submit button it should show the corresponding `username`. For this see the below codes

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String URLGET = "http://my_ip:8000/app/web/users/";
String result = "";
TextView tv;
public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);


    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String reqURL = URLGET;

            new RestOperation().execute(reqURL);
            //callWebService(query);
        }
    });

}

public class RestOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String content;
    String error;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    String data = "";

    TextView getData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getData);
    EditText userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterId);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        try {
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "-" + userInput.getText();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);


            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            }

            content = sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (error != null) {
            getData.setText("Error" + error);
        } else {
            getData.setText(content);


        }
    }
}
```

}

But when i run the app, enter any given id's and perform submit. The progress bat shows up for a long while and then the app crashes giving the following errors.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                           Process: com.example.accurat.webservice, PID: 642
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedReader.close()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.accurat.webservice.MainActivity$RestOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:141)
                                                                            at com.example.accurat.webservice.MainActivity$RestOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
02-07 15:57:42.929 642-642/com.example.accurat.webservice E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.accurat.webservice.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3f2c8572 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,322} that was originally added here
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                           at com.example.accurat.webservice.MainActivity$RestOperation.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:90)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
                                                                           at com.example.accurat.webservice.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I searched many articles on google and couldn't find the correct answers, though i tried to implement them but still no result.

Below are the findings from my search.

1. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478479/6854117)
2. [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7713264/6854117)
3. [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28577375/6)
4. [link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28577375/6)

**Update 1**

By using `Ben` and `X3Btel` suggestions my app stops crashing but it's showing me below error on emulator

[image]

I then again replaced my `ip` to `localhost` but still saw the same error.

I am testing my app on the emulator so i put my `ip` address in the url.

I am stuck to from almost all the day. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First- move your findViewByID in the Activity onCreate, as well as the creation of the ProgressBar - this should fix your leakage.

Comment: @X3Btel  Thank you for the comment, but if move `findViewByID` into the `onCreate` method then i will face syntax errors in `Async`

Comment: @Ben answer should fix your issue. Still using findViewByID in the Async as bad practice you dont need the views inside- you could pass the value of userInput, and then on postExecute access public field of the Activity to set the result

Comment: Yes as i have said already that my app is not crashing but showing me this error. I have initialized them in the main class then done `findViewById` in `onCreate` and then on `postExecute` accessed there public field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a nullpointer exception.

if exception happened before initializing the reader it will lead to this error because br.close() is placed in finally block. It's good practice to **always check for null** before closing resources in finally.

try this in finally block

```
if(br!= null)
br.close();
```

Good luck

Comment: Ben answer should fixed your problem.

Comment: It did solve my problem, but a new error comes, can you please see it.